# Connect to API that needs an access token with PHP (without Laravel)

Tags: php, api, curl, token

I'm trying to access to an API that needs and Access Token but I don't know how to implement the token part. This is how I connect to the API. What is wrong in my code?

```
$ch = curl_init();

$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Im5aTHhod...';
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    $authorization,
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a matter of constructing the header, give this a try:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Im5aTHhod'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```